# Global array resets on next page

Tags: javascript, global-variables

I have the following function, that takes a string from an input, and puts it inside a global array, but as I go to the next page, the global array gets empty, as if nothing happened.

```
checkItems = [];
function addToCart() {
    "use strict";
    var p = document.getElementById('buy-item-input').value;
    var verifyItem = 0;
        /* some other code... */
        checkItems.push(p);
        location.href = 'pay.html';
}
```

I've put console.log before chaning the window just to verify that the array gets the data before going to the next page, and it does, but when I try it again at the next page, it's gone...

Comment: As HTTP is stateless, every time you load the page it will use the initial values of whatever you set in JavaScript. You can't set a global variable in JS and simply make that value stay after loading the page again.

Comment: I guess your website is simply not a [SPA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application) and therefore everything starts new when clicking a link.

Comment: you could use cookies or a database to store the value and then retrieve it when neede.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Persist variables between page loads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29986657/persist-variables-between-page-loads)

Answer (score 0):

You can store the value in another place using **Query String**, **Web Storage**, **Cookies** or **Windows Name**

Check this answer for more info:

[Persist variables between page loads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29986657/persist-variables-between-page-loads)

Comment: Let me know if you need more help.